# Unable to load item prototype in NSCollectionView

Tags: macos, swift, prototype, nscollectionview

When executing `self.colSoundEffects.itemPrototype = self.storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("SoundEffect_Item") as? NSCollectionViewItem` in my Swift application, I receive the following error messages, and my view does not load:

```
2015-07-16 15:01:21.790 SoundBoardFX[48244:19680526] -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:]: corrupt and unarchivable nib file
2015-07-16 15:01:21.791 SoundBoardFX[48244:19680526] *** Assertion failure in -[NSStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1348.17/AppKit.subproj/Storyboarding/NSStoryboard.m:208
2015-07-16 15:01:21.791 SoundBoardFX[48244:19680526] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): Could not load the scene view controller for identifier 'SoundEffect_Item'
```

I've double-checked all of my identifiers, and as far as I can tell, everything is in working order. When I remove that line, my view loads without a problem (sans the item prototype, of course).

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

I'm running OS X 10.10.4, Xcode 6.4 (6E35b).

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a new Storyboard with the "SoundEffect_Item" viewController ? You could copy-past it to a new Story to see if the earlier story is corrupted.

Comment: Yes, I did, and I get the exact same error. I even tried creating an entirely new project, and it didn't help.

Comment: i would checkout self.storyboard to see that it points to the right object. and also whether contentViewController is setup correctly in the IB